# Covariance of two functions, multiplication rules of the second moment as $E(aX^2)$

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value, covariance

Since $Cov(X,Y) = E(XY)-E(X)E(Y)$, I have to somehow define **E(XY)**.
I know what $E(X)$ and $E(Y)$ are, also I know $Var(X)$ and $Var(Y)$. $Y$ and $X$ are defined by **two independent random variables** which appear in both:
$$X= 5a + 3b - 5$$ and
$$Y= -3a + 5b - 1$$

$a$ and $b$ respectively have also their own EVs and variances that are just defined as some constant, for example 5 and 6, and 7 and 8. I can work out all the EVs and variances, but I run into problem, when forming the E(XY) for the covariance.

I get a term where I have some constant $c$ multiplying the second moment of EV in the following way:
$E(ca^2)$

I do know that $Var(a)=E(a^2)-(E(a))^2$ and can workout that $E(a^2)=Var(a)+(E(a))^2$, since the $Var(a)$ and $E(a)$ are known. Therefore I should be able plug something in for the $E(a^2)$.

But now comes the real question: *is it fine* to take the constant out as follows:
$E(c*a^2)=cE(a^2)$
and now plug $E(a^2)$ from this one $E(a^2)=Var(a)+(E(a))^2$?

For this example I just used case for variable $a$ but same sort dilemma is also presented with cases where there is $E(kb^2)$, $k$ being a constant.

*As a separate pondering:*
I have a gut feeling that the $Cov(X,Y)$ shall not be zero ($X$ and $Y$ are not independent which is algebraically quite clear, I dare to say) despite in the beginning we cannot say anything about the values of X regardless of knowing what Y put out and vice-versa. The underlying variables as $a$ and $b$ are independent and they can get pretty much any real values, but for sure we know, that if for example $a$ and $b$ both were zero, the $X$ would -5 and $Y$ would be -1.

Thus $P(X = 0, Y = 0) = 0 ≠ P(X=0)P(Y=0)$ and the variables are not independent.

If someone wants to have take on this last part, it would be nice, but really want the answer for the $E(c*a^2)=cE(a^2)$  situation, if it's allowed or not.

*Edit, example, why I believe that covariance is not 0.*

Let's set that E(a)=1 and E(b)=2,
and that Var(a)= 3 and Var(b)=4.
Then E(X) = 6 and E(Y)=6.
Also $E(a^2) = 4, E(b^2) = 8$.
Let's then calculate the $Cov(X,Y)=E(XY)−E(X)E(Y)$.
$E(X)E(Y)=36$.

Let's then figure out $E(XY)=E((5a+4b-5)(-3a+5b-1))=E(-15a^2+16ab+10a+15b^2-28b+5)$

Now let's calculate each EV-term and then sum separately like this: $E(-15a^2)+E(16ab)+E(10a)+E(15b^2)+E(-28b)+E(5)=-15E(a^2)+16E(a)E(b)+10E(a)+15E(b^2)-28E(b)+5$

Bow let's put in everything we know: $-15(4) + 16(1)(2) + 10(1) +15(8)-28(2)+5=-60+32+10+120-56+5=51$
Then subtrarcting both terms:
$Cov(X,Y)=E(XY)−E(X)E(Y)=51-36=15$

Edit2:
Only thing making the $Cov(X,Y)=0$ would be to square the $a^2$ and $b^2$ values inside the following expression or with the constants taken out: (if squaring allowed, then the expression would equal $36, 36-36 = 0$)  $E(-15a^2)+E(16ab)+E(10a)+E(15b^2)+E(-28b)+E(5)$  but in the first place I understood that it's not allowed, instead we have to use these values: $E(a^2) = 4, E(b^2) = 8$

Comment: Well, $E(cX^2) = \int c X^2 \ dP = c\int X^2 \ dP = cE(X^2)$... taking a constant out of an expectation is always okay.

Comment: I don't see how $P(X = 0, Y = 0) = 0$ or $0 \ne P(X=0)P(Y=0)$ follow...

Comment: @SeanRoberson Thanks, this was the confirmation I was looking for! Had gotten the integral just on the paper to dwell on it, but neither I was sure I could integrate over the P to get EX. But in the end, it's quite intuitive.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I am not sure. I would say that $P(X=0, Y=0)=0$ since if X is 0, with some $a$ and $b$, it's impossible for Y to 0 with the same $a$ and $b$. But there certainly exists a probability for seperate cases $P(X=0)P(Y=0)$, therefore the "not equal" symbol. The thing is, can we kind of go "backwards" to asses the parameters of each distribution and the compare the end results.

Comment: How do you _prove_ that the same $a$ and $b$ cannot give $X=0$ and $Y=0$? (hint: you can't prove this; the system of two equations $5a+3b=5$, $-3a+5b=1$ certainly have a solution!)

Comment: "certainly exists" doesn't convince me. How do you _show_ that $P(X=0)\ne0$?????

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I try to get my head around all this in an hour, I get what you mean totally, but if it then follows from your reasoning in any case that: $P(X=0,Y=0)=P(X=0)P(Y=0)$, then the Cov(X,Y) would be zero, which isn't he case here given the first answer I received.

Comment: No, that equation does not follow from my reasoning. I have no reasoning here, I've just been wondering why you think that inequality  is true. So far it appears that you have no reason at all. (No, that inequality would not imply Cov=0.)

Comment: I also have no idea why you believe $Cov\ne0$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Added my reasoning to the end of the original post, to explain, why I think the Cov(X,Y) isn't zero. Please point a mistake, if there's one.

Comment: You still haven't explained why $P(X=0,Y=0)\ne P(X=0)P(Y=0)$.

Comment: You have some typos including saying $28(2)$ is $64$ rather than $56$.  That does not change your point.

Comment: To get $Cov(X,Y)=0$ in this question, you need $Var(a)=Var(b)$, because $Cov(X,Y)=15 Var(b) - 15Var(a)$

Comment: @Henry thanks for your input, good and handy take by you. Corrected the typo. But couldn't the $Cov(X,Y)=0$ if the E(X) and E(Y) had some fitting properties despite them having common and independent "underlying" variables. Of course the variances can be defined via expected values, but could there be some really intuitive case, where you clearly see zero covariance between two distributions that still have common $a$ and $b$ or such. Just wondering, nothing necessary for this question anymore, though.

Comment: Iff $a$ and $b$ have the same variance then $Cov(X,Y)=0$.  If  $a$ and $b$ are independently normally distributed and have the same variance then $X$ and $Y$ are independent and normally distributed, but in most other cases will not be independent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> by **two independent random variables** which appear in both:

Because $a, b$ *are independent*: $\mathsf E(ab)=\mathsf E(a)\,\mathsf E(b)$, so...

$\qquad\begin{align}\mathsf E(XY) &=\mathsf E((5a + 3b - 5)~(-3a + 5b - 1))\\ &=  \mathsf E(5 + 10 a - 15 a^2 - 28 b + 16 a b + 15 b^2)\\& = 5+10\,\mathsf E(a) -15\,\mathsf E(a^2) -28\,\mathsf E(b) +16\,\mathsf E(ab)+15\,\mathsf E(b^2)\\& = 5+10\,\mathsf E(a) -15\,\mathsf E(a^2) -28\,\mathsf E(b) +16\,\mathsf E(a)\,\mathsf E(b)+15\,\mathsf E(b^2)\\&=5+10\,\mathsf E(a)-15(\mathsf{Var}(a)+\mathsf E(a)^2)-28\mathsf E(b)+16\mathsf E(a)\mathsf E(b)+15(\mathsf {Var}(b^2)-\mathsf E(b)^2)\\\mathsf E(X)\mathsf E(Y) &=5+10\,\mathsf E(a) -15\,\mathsf E(a)^2 -28\,\mathsf E(b) +16\,\mathsf E(a)\,\mathsf E(b)+15\,\mathsf E(b)^2\\[2ex]\mathsf{Cov}(X,Y)&=-15\mathsf{Var}(a)+15\mathsf{Var}(b)\end{align}$

---

> I have a gut feeling that the Cov(X,Y) shall not be zero (X and Y are not independent which is algebraicly quite clear, I dare to say)

Independence always entails zero covariance, **but** some dependent variables *may* also have zero covariance.  Covariance is a measure of *linear correlation*.

$$P\to Q\text{ does not mean }\lnot P\to\lnot Q$$

Comment: Yeah, this is a fine, very fine, answer. Got my stuff right already, despite the typos, but explanation about covariances nature is good.